# GLSL shaders crashng ATI/AMD GPU

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've been working on a project and the lab computers are packed with ATI series 6700. The project is in C++ with OpenGL, so for the shaders I use GLSL. It is basically a planet with Level of Detail, so the number of polygons being sent to the shaders depends on camera position and the closer you are the more polygons there are for better definition. Bear in mind that I have indeed put a limit on the level of detail, otherwise everything would crash when camera was too close, due to insane amount of subdivisions.

However, when running the program on the lab computers, there's weird twitching of the mesh (some vertices appearing at other positions) and most importantly, there's a drop in framerate when I get too close and eventually the whole thing freezes and both my screens turn black and when Windows is visible again there's a message saying the drivers have encountered a problem and had to recover.

I tried running my project on my personal laptop which has an nvidia GT555M and none of the above problems appear. No twitching, no drop in framerate and no crashing. Also, when I disable the shaders in the lab computers, the program doesn't crash, nor is there twitching, but there's still the drop in framerate. All of this makes me think it has something to do with the way NVidia and ATI interpret and compile GLSL.

First of all, I should say I'm only creating a VBO with 17x17 vertices, where each vertex has only 16 bytes, 3 floats for position and 4 bytes of padding for performance. So when creating the VBO and drawing it, I do not enable COLOR, TEXTURE or NORMAL, since there's only information about the vertex position.

On the GPU side, however, I might be using non-standard GLSL or something like that, since I've read that ATI cards can only work with standardized GLSL. So here's my vertex shader and fragment shader:

http://pastebin.com/DE6ijidq
http://pastebin.com/Q8xUAguw

Bear in mind that what the C++ does is create 6 grids of 16 by 16 squares, each for one side of the cube, but has them centered on the origin, so in the first line of the main I displace them accordingly to create a cube, then I use the exploding cube technique to make it a sphere and work on it. I don't specify a GLSL version and I'm using varying variables, which might be where the problem is. Is there a way to make this compatible with the ATI cards as well? Should I specify a version, if so, which one? And should I use in and out variables, but then how? I've been testing my shaders in RenderMonkey and for some reason it still uses varying.

Comment: Do the lab machines have the latest version of Catalyst Control Centre? (AMD drivers, the latest version being 12.6).

Comment: I need to check, should that fix the issues? I might not be able to update due to administrator permissions, but if not I will have to ask the ones responsible for the lab.

Comment: I can't say if it should fix the issues. It may fix the issues, it may not, but it is something that should be done.

Comment: That enormous int array was causing the twitching and the crash, after changing it to a texture lookup I've fixed as much, but it's still slow and profiling proves that atiglext.dll or something is where the CPU spends most time, whereas in the laptop with NVidia everything runs smoothly

Comment: I've found it helpful to put a [#version](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Core_Language#Version) statement at the top, it allows the shader compiler to spit out some extra warnings or errors.